# When should I close writer for interceptor?

Tags: java, apache, logging, cxf

I have set up apache cxf and loggers for it, I have next logical steps

```
public SoapResults getMySoapData()
{
    myWeb.createLogWriters(myServiceBean); // here I set up endpoint, add interceptors, etc.
    SoapResults result = myServiceBean.searchSomeData();
    myWeb.closeLogWriters(myServiceBean); // here I close interceptors' writers so all log data should be available in file
}
```

And actually I have no request/response details written in files (and if I add some strings, they are written correctly. So, the question is whether I am closing my interceptors in time or I should close them later (after server response or smth else) ? What should I do to see log data in file ?

**update**

I have next code when creating loggers: `inInterceptor = new LoggingInInterceptor(writer); outInterceptor = new LoggingOutInterceptor(writer);`

add them to the endpoint:

`endpoint.getInInterceptors().add(inInterceptor) endpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(outInterceptor)`

and they are available when I close them

Comment: If the service doesn't write the request/response data to the log then maybe your interceptor should do that (e.g. manually call a method to log `result`).

Comment: @Thomas I've updated question with some details. Please take a look.

Comment: I'm not an expert in CXF so I'd have to guess here, but why do you have to use a writer manually anyways? Why not use a logging framework and let it handle the writers?

Comment: @Thomas actually interceptors is a built-in feature and it allows to write logs exactly at the moment when request comes and in a specififc format